# Using lock() for collection in ToString() method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've faced myself in a situation, when my overridden `ToString()` method would use one of the instance's collections.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string returnStr = "testString";

    lock (_sync)
    {
        returnStr = $"{returnStr}: {string.Join(",", _testList)}";  // where _testList is a List<string> in the class's scope
    }

    return returnStr;
}
```

Since we are talking about a multi-threaded application, I was wondering, since I would have to use `lock()` inside the `ToString()` method's body in order to avoid the collection's modification while my return string is being generated. While I'm doing modifications on the collection, the same object (`_sync`) is being locked, of course.
But, this method is being used by several other processes as well, such as the Visual Studio's Debugger and who knows what else, since this method is being inherited from the `Object` class itself.
**For example:** I fear that it might being called more often behind the scene (by the framework or anything else), and would have to use the locking (which could lead to performance loss), or it might cause deadlock while I'm debugging in a bad moment.

**Question:**
Should I care about this situation, since it could cause problems, or is it OK to use object locking inside `ToString()` (and in other inherited methods from .net types)?

Are there any better alternative solutions in order to achieve this same goal?

*Note: I was thinking about to generate the required string from the collection every time when that is being modified (inside the lock, where it is being manipulated), so I would have the collection's string format ready to be concatenated in the `ToString()` method itself. I guess it would be even better for performance, since the process of `string.Join()` wouldn't have to run at every call of `ToString()`, but I'm really curious to know more about this situation.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special rules for `ToString` when it comes to thread safety. Thread safety is a global property of your program. You must understand and control everything that accesses data concurrently.

If there is a chance that a `ToString` might occur concurrently with writes to the data that it accesses there must be appropriate synchronization. It is in particular unsafe to read from a `List` in the presence of concurrent writes.

Since your critical region inside of `ToString` only uses one lock and does not block there is little risk of deadlocking. Once the lock is entered it is guaranteed to be exited eventually. This is a good design principle for locking in general.

Maybe you can make use of lock-free patterns such as immutable collections? Or maybe you can make your entire object immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need/use the `ToString()` that often? 
Your scenario seems more of a business logic and I wouldn't mix it up with the `ToString()` implementation.

I would go for something like: `GetSnapshotRepresentation()` that uses locks and the whole conundrum and leave `ToString()` returning something very lightweight (e.g. id, type, something immutable, etc.)

Putting locks and that heavy machinery into `ToString()` you will block your writers if you make calls to `ToString()` that you didn't want/needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about deadlocks in this situation. A deadlock requires at least 2 locks and you only have one. The List class itself does not use any locks and neither do string.Join or string.Format.

Whether or not it is a performance issue is entirely down to how these other applications you mention are using it. The Visual Studio debugger will not call ToString very often and then only when you're paused in the debugger! This will not be a problem.

As to the other applications you mention, you will only know by profiling.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about deadlocks because, as @DavidJ said, they don't happen with only one lock.  You should be concerned with [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) however.

Let's suppose that in addition to your ToString method, you have a method to remove every other item in your list.

```
for(int i = _testList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2)
{
    _testList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Since your application is multithreaded, your ToString() could be called while another thread is in the middle of this loop.  You might think that you need to lock all accesses to your list like this:

```
for(int i = _testList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2)
{
    lock (_sync) {
        _testList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

The problem here is: suppose your loop has iterated a couple of times but gets interrupted before it completes.  If the thread that interrupts the loop calls ToString(), the ToString() method will output a list that is in an inconsistent state.  Accesses to your list from other threads shouldn't happen inside the loop.  You'll actually have to put the lock outside of the loop like this:

```
lock(_sync) {
    for(int i = _testList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2)
    {
        _testList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to illustrate here is that there are no simple rules for multithreaded code.  Your ToString() method is thread-safe as long as other parts of your code are also thread-safe.